# Update all icons of a JLabel ArrayList efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, jlabel, imageicon

So, I want to update every icon of a JLabel ArrayList, to its own individual icon based off of an outside ArrayList. The outside ArrayList is called *board*, and the JLabel ArrayList is called *tiles*. I want to update every icon to its corresponding item in *board*, how can I do that efficiently? I need it to update every icon of a huge list, we're talking like 100 - 200 items long. Right now, at a hundred items long, it takes about 4 seconds before displaying all of the icons at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
    //this is all one line:
    tiles.get(i).setIcon(resizeIcon(displayTile(board.get(i), 
    tiles.get(i).getHeight(), tiles.get(i).getHeight()));
}
//this resizes the ImageIcon and returns the risized icon:
public static ImageIcon resizeIcon(ImageIcon i, int x, int y) {
    Image image = i.getImage();
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(x, y, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
    i = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    return i;
}
//this returns an ImageIcon based off of the number that is put in:
public static ImageIcon displayTile(int num) {
    if (num != 0) {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/resources/" + num + ".png");
        return i;
    }
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/resources/0.png");
    return i;
}
```

How do I make it more effecient?

Comment: How many different `num`s will there be? Could you cache the result of `displayTile(num)` for each of the possibilities?

Comment: How many different sizes will there be? If all the files are the same size, could you cache the resized results of caching `displayTile(num)`?

Comment: the nums will change, but I could possibly have public resized icons, and just access them instead of having to resize them every time, if that is what you're saying.

Comment: @Andy Turner dude thanks! it works, and its sooooooooo much faster!!